# docker bind mounts sometimes empty

Tags: docker, bind, mount

I am using a docker container with this definition:

```
  webserver:
    image: ghcr.io/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx:latest
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-Micron_1100_MTFDDAV256TBN_17501A32891E-part3/dockerconfig/paperless/data:/usr/src/paperless/data
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-DataPool1/Paperless/paperless_ng_media:/usr/src/paperless/media
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-DataPool1/Paperless/export:/usr/src/paperless/export
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-DataPool1/Paperless/consume:/usr/src/paperless/consume
```

Sometimes, unfortunately, the content of `/usr/src/paperless/media` inside the container is empty. All files created now endup inside the container and not in the bind mount.

Restarting the container usually helps.
I have not observed any errors in journalctl -u docker
docker inspect correctly shows:

```
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/srv/dev-disk-by-label-DataPool1/Paperless/paperless_ng_media:/usr/src/paperless/media:rw",
                "/srv/dev-disk-by-label-DataPool1/Paperless/export:/usr/src/paperless/export:rw",
                "/srv/dev-disk-by-label-DataPool1/Paperless/consume:/usr/src/paperless/consume:rw",
                "/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-Micron_1100_MTFDDAV256TBN_17501A32891E-part3/dockerconfig/paperless/data:/usr/src/paperless/data:rw"
            ],
```

There is not much special with the folder `/srv/dev-disk-by-label-DataPool1/Paperless/paperless_ng_media` except that it is a btrfs subvolume:

````
/dev/sdc1 on /srv/dev-disk-by-label-DataPool1 type btrfs 
/dev/sdc1 on /srv/dev-disk-by-label-DataPool1/Paperless type btrfs (rw,noatime,space_cache=v2,subvolid=1385,subvol=/Paperless)```

I am out of ideas..
Do you have any?

Best regards,
Hendrik
````

Comment: Just guesses, there no permissions or Selinux (or Apparmor) problem?

Comment: The problem is coming (without container restart) and going (with container restart).  So, it cannot be permissions. How would I track town Selinux or Apparmor problems?